# JavaScript Event Handlers Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to add two event handlers by different methods, one using document.getElementById, and the other using inline css. The issue I am experiencing is that only the inline call to a JS function works. I can not find any issues, after viewing various examples online. 
Thanks in advance.

Html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Dynamic Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="button.js"></script>
    <button type="button" id="AButton" onmouseover="DisplayAlert2();">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function DisplayAlert1(){
    window.alert("Alert 1");
}

function DisplayAlert2(){
    window.alert("Alert 2");
}

var AButtonJS = document.getElementById("AButton");
AButtonJS.onclick = DisplayAlert1;
```

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FE6Q3/  `DisplayAlert2()` is in the html, but that gets overridden with `DisplayAlert1()` due to your initialization script.  Is this run after the dom is loaded? (at least after `AButton` in the html?)

Comment: How does assigning to the ***onclick*** property replace the value of the ***onmouseover*** listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the script element is loaded and (almost certainly) executed before the button element exists in the DOM. Swap their positions and it should work fine:

```
<button type="button" id="AButton" onmouseover="DisplayAlert2();">Button</button>
<script src="button.js"></script>
```

Scripts that modify the DOM should be called after the load event, or DOM ready, or just placed immediately before the closing body tag so that they are executed after the DOM has loaded.

Incidentally, the *type* attribute for script elemetns is only necessary if the script isn't javascript. Also, function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors so call your functions *displayAlert1* and *displayAlert2*.